# Prerequisite mathematics for nonlinear systems

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation, nonlinear-system

I have a background in electrical engineering and linear control systems. I want to learn nonlinear systems.  There is a book [Nonlinear systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130673897) by Hassan K. Khalil. The book has a lot of advanced mathematics with proofs. My question is, are there some good books to learn the math that is in this book?

Comment: Very often such books briefly discuss the prerequisites within the introduction. Does Khalil not do so?

Comment: @311411 Thank you for your reply. For mathematics the author of the book suggests the “usual level” of calculus, differential equations and matrix theory for graduate level students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some (linear) algebra, analysis, and dynamical systems for that book.

For linear algebra and analysis, any book would do the job.

For dynamical systems you may look at the books by Strogatz, "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos" or by M.W. Hirsch, S. Smale, and R.L. Devaney, "Differential equations, dynamical systems, and an introduction to chaos". They are both quite accessible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll take a look at those books.